# WIndows 11 firewall rule doesn't seem to work

Tags: networking, windows-11, windows-firewall

I have a web server on a Windows 11 Pro PC running on port 12080. I can access http://localhost:12080 just fine, but can't access from any other PC on the same network.

I added a firewall rule allowing the inbound port of 12080 TCP for all three profiles (Domain, Private, and Public). No success. The firewall log for "Public" shows the packets are dropped:

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60715 12080 52 S 2253698716 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60716 12080 52 S 2119116775 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60717 12080 52 S 3702646266 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

192.168.195.114 = Browser PC 192.168.195.142 = Web server PC

The firewall logs for Domain and Private show nothing.

I can Remote Desktop from the Browser PC to the Web PC, and ping the Web PC just fine. I just can't get to the web page. If I disable the firewall, the web page comes up just fine from any PC.

Thoughts?

[Screenshot of firewall rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQXWG.jpg)

The firewall rules are for JMRI - I've tried various rules to no avail. The Zulu Platform is Java used by JMRI.

Comment: Please add screenshots showing the definition of the firewall rule.

Comment: is the web server only listening on localhost perhaps? i.e. can you access `http://192.168.195.142:12080` from within the web server?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the firewall rules to the bottom of the original ask.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. I can use either http://192.168.195.142:12080/ or http://localhost:12080/.  What is interesting is that I later installed IIS on port 80 and it works just fine from the remote PC. And I couldn't see anything special about the firewall rules that were added.